# Cancan Undefined Method 'user' Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm running into problems defining user permissions in my cancan controller:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
    can :read, :all
    can :update, User do |user|  
      user.try(:user) == user  
    end
    end
  end
end
```

This results in a NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `user' for #<User:0x000001050914c8>
```

When I try and edit / update a user. Everything else seems just fine.

Any help appreciated

Bob

Comment: Whats `user.try(:user) == user` for ? Is there a method called `user` in your `User` model ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that

```
user.try(:user) == user
```

is basically trying to execute `user.user == user`

Looks like you're trying to only let users update the User model attributes if the User instance in question is the logged-in user.

Try this instead:

```
can :update, User, :id => user.id
```

Which is saying "Can update the User model when `@user.id` is the same as the `current_user.id`."

Your block notation is ambiguous since your block variable `|user|` is the same as the `user` passed in to the Ability model.

---

As a side-note for those still getting a grip on Ruby,

```
can :update, User, :id => user.id
```

is the same as:

```
can(:update, User, { id: user.id })
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. That worked perfectly. Am new to rails and sometime struggle to find the wood for the trees.