# CanCan stopping Devise redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I'm using Devise & CanCan for my app. When a user signs in, they are taken to their account page - I have set up a custom redirect for this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    url_for :controller => '/users', :id => current_user.id, :action => 'myaccount'
end
```

However, when I try and do the same for when the user registers - i.e. using after_sign_up_path_for(resource), then I am given this error:

```
 NoMethodError in UsersController#show

undefined method `user' for #<User:0x25d15e8>
```

It is referring to the ability.rb file that I set up for CanCan, which is the following:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    can :manage, :all do |all|
        all.try(:user) == user
    end
```

The line it is saying is the problem is all.try(:user) == user. I don't understand why this is causing a problem? It seems to be that no matter what I put for the redirect, it will always take me to e.g. {app}/users/22 and give this error.

Comment: you probably want to split that up into models instead of trying that.  it will be easier to read and to manipulate later if you need to update the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208679/cancan-undefined-method-user-problems) that tells that you are trying to execute `user.try(:user) == user` which is the source of all your problems.

So you can use `can :manage, :all, :id => user.id` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that has stopped the error from occuring. However, when I have registered a new user, they are still being redirected to /user/:id, instead of user/:id/myaccount as specified in the redirect. Any idea why?

Comment: Is the redirect still occur if you remove `can :manage` code?

Comment: If I take away the can :manage block, then the user gets redirected to the root url with an access denied exception. It's strange, because if I manually type the url when the error screen appears, it allows access to the correct page, and I still get the 'successful sign up' flash as well.